# I have a data source table that may have or may not have certain columns

Tags: excel-formula, match

I have a table of information that I have used Sumifs to get the data i need, but sometimes a part of the data may drop out ie. apple may be there one month but not the next. When I get the table without the same number of columns as the month before the  sumifs don't pull the correct data with out manipulating the source document or my formulas. I am sure that there is a way around this using an index match formula but I haven't had success.
I have sample data if someone can help? Thank you.

Comment: please post sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data in a table to maintain the structure.

```
SUMIFS(Table1[Hats],Table1[Month],">"&C4,Table1[Month],"<"&C5)
```

[image]